# Reassign google map var to new div

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, reactjs

I'm using react and I have a component that renders a google map view when it mounts. 
I'd like to save the google map var globally and when so that when the component is unmounted then remounted I can just reassign the map to a div instead of recreating it. Is this possible?

So Something like this

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var React      = require('react');

window.coverage_map = null;

var  CoverageMap =  React.createClass({

    componentDidMount: function(){   
        if(window.coverage_map == null){      
           var ele = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.map);
           window.coverage_map = new google.maps.Map(ele, {
               center: {lat: 37.7833, lng: -122.4167},
               mapTypeControlOptions: {
                  mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
               }
            });
        }
        else{
           //reassign google map
        }
   },
   render(){
     // render code
   },
})
```

Comment: can you provide a demo of your current application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - the root element of a map cannot be changed once instantiated.